# MFMailComposeViewController programmatically call the "Send" button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to send an automatic email with an UIImage as an
attachment when user presses 'Send Photo' button.
Is there any way that we can programmatically call the "Send" button in the MFMailComposeViewController. If not could you please suggest me some other method of doing this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: The documentation for MFMailComposeViewController very specifically says that you cannot do this. You'll either have to directly connect to a mail exchanger and send it yourself or send the data to some server you write and then mail it from there.

Answer (score 6):

Apple might reject your submission for this, but if you really wanna do it, here's how:

```
-(void)showController {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController;
    //alloc, init, set properties, do whatever you normally would
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
    [mailController release];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(hackMail:) userInfo:mailController repeats:NO];
}

-(void)hackMail:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = theTimer.userInfo;
    UIBarButtonItem *sendBtn = mailController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem;
    id targ = sendBtn.target;
    [targ performSelector:sendBtn.action withObject:sendBtn];
}
```

This will show a mail controller, wait 3 seconds, and then send the e-mail. Happy hacking :)

Comment: Has anyone had this rejected?